# make concurrent RCurl GET requests for set of URLs

Tags: r, url-rewriting, rcurl, sapply

I wrote a function to use RCurl to obtain the effective URL for a list of shortened URL redirects (bit.ly, t.co, etc.) and handle errors when the effective URL locates a document (PDFs tend to throw "Error in curlPerform... embedded nul in string.")

I would like to make this function more efficiently if possible (while keeping it in R). As written the run-time is prohibitively long for un-shortening a thousand or more URLs.

`?getURI` tells us that by default, getURI/getURL goes asynchronous when the length of the url vector is >1.  But my performance seems totally linear, presumably because `sapply` turns the thing into one big for loop and the concurrency is lost.

Is there anyway I can speed up these requests?  Extra credit for fixing the "embedded nul" issue.

```
require(RCurl)

options(RCurlOptions = list(verbose = F, followlocation = T,
                        timeout = 500, autoreferer = T, nosignal = T,
                        useragent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_2)"))

# find successful location (or error msg) after any redirects
getEffectiveUrl <- function(url){ 
  c = getCurlHandle()
  h = basicHeaderGatherer()
  curlSetOpt( .opts = list(header=T, verbose=F), curl= c, .encoding = "CE_LATIN1")
  possibleError <- tryCatch(getURI( url, curl=c, followlocation=T, 
                                    headerfunction = h$update, async=T),
                            error=function(e) e)  
  if(inherits(possibleError, "error")){
    effectiveUrl <- "ERROR_IN_PAGE" # fails on linked documents (PDFs etc.)
  } else { 
    headers <- h$value()
    names(headers) <- tolower(names(headers)) #sometimes cases change on header names?
    statusPrefix <- substr(headers[["status"]],1,1) #1st digit of http status
    if(statusPrefix=="2"){ # status = success
      effectiveUrl <- getCurlInfo(c)[["effective.url"]]
    } else{ effectiveUrl <- paste(headers[["status"]] ,headers[["statusmessage"]]) } 
  }
  effectiveUrl
}

testUrls <- c("http://t.co/eivRJJaV4j","http://t.co/eFfVESXE2j","http://t.co/dLI6Q0EMb0",
              "http://www.google.com","http://1.uni.vi/01mvL","http://t.co/05Mz00DHLD",
              "http://t.co/30aM6L4FhH","http://www.amazon.com","http://bit.ly/1fwWZLK",
              "http://t.co/cHglxQkz6Z") # 10th URL redirects to content w/ embedded nul
system.time(
  effectiveUrls <- sapply(X= testUrls, FUN=getEffectiveUrl, USE.NAMES=F)
) # takes 7-10 secs on my laptop

# does Vectorize help? 
vGetEffectiveUrl <- Vectorize(getEffectiveUrl, vectorize.args = "url")
system.time(
  effectiveUrls2 <- vGetEffectiveUrl(testUrls)
) # nope, makes it worse
```

Comment: It looks like you should be giving `getURIAsynchronous` a vector of urls. But the interface is pretty hairy, and it's not obvious how you override the writer to capture the headers instead of the body. You should also be setting `nobody = 1L` to avoid retrieving the body (which you don't need)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had bad experience with RCurl and Async request. R would completely freeze (though no error message, CPU and RAM did not spike) with only concurrent 20 requests.

I recommend switching to CURL and using curl_fetch_multi() function. It my case it could easily handle 50000 JSON request in one pool (with some division into subpools under the hood).
https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/curl/vignettes/intro.html#async_requests